# FileSystemWatcher doesn't detect JPG rotation on Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, windows-10, filesystemwatcher

There is a `FileSystemWatcher` in our WPF application that monitors a directory and shows a live view of the files in this directory. Each time the folder changes (a file is created, renamed, deleted or changed), the `FileSystemWatcher` refreshes this live view.

We have noticed the `FileSystemWatcher` events are not triggered when a JPG file is rotated by using the **rotate buttons** in **Windows Explorer** (it does work with PNG, BMP, TIFF and TIF files):

[image: Rotate buttons]

Doubleclicking the file and rotating the JPG in the **photo app** does trigger the events, so there must be a difference here.

I have only been able to test it on Windows 10 but my coworker confirms it worked in previous Windows versions.

**Is there a way to detect a JPG file rotation using the `FileSystemWatcher` or is this a known bug?**

The issue can be tested by using the following code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("The file " + e.Name + " was " + e.ChangeType);
    }
```

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but you're only filtering `NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size` and rotation is `NotifyFilters.LastWrite`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's most likely because in JPEG rotation is usually controlled with EXIF metadata flag. So when you rotate jpeg in explorer - no actual rotation is performed. Instead it just changes EXIF Rotation value (which can be 0,1,2,3 etc as I remember). When you open file in some viewer - it reads rotation flag and performs rotation for display. Because flag has fixed size (takes fixed number of bytes in file) - this operation does not change size of the file, and you only track size changes. To fix - add `NotifyFilters.LastWrite` to your `FileSystemWatcher` filter. There are other operations that do not change size of a file, so doing this is beneficial anyway.

Comment: Or just don't set NotifyFilter at all. Keep its default value, i.e. LastWrite, FileName, and DirectoryName.